# Nginx Ingress controller - Error when getting IngressClass nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster `v1.22.1` set up in bare metal CentOS. I am facing a problem when setting up Nginx Ingress controller following [this link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/).

I followed exactly the same in step 1-3 but got a `CrashLoopBackOff` error in nginx ingress controller pod. I checked the logs of the pod and found below:

```
[root@dev1 deployments]# kubectl logs -n nginx-ingress nginx-ingress-5cd5c7549d-hw6l7
I0910 23:15:20.729196       1 main.go:271] Starting NGINX Ingress controller Version=1.12.1 GitCommit=6f72db6030daa9afd567fd7faf9d5fffac9c7c8f Date=2021-09-08T13:39:53Z PlusFlag=false
W0910 23:15:20.770569       1 main.go:310] The '-use-ingress-class-only' flag will be deprecated and has no effect on versions of kubernetes >= 1.18.0. Processing ONLY resources that have the 'ingressClassName' field in Ingress equal to the class.
F0910 23:15:20.774788       1 main.go:314] Error when getting IngressClass nginx: the server could not find the requested resource
```

I believe I have the IngressClass setup properly as shown in below:

```
[root@dev1 deployments]# kubectl get IngressClass
NAME    CONTROLLER                     PARAMETERS   AGE
nginx   nginx.org/ingress-controller   <none>       2m12s
```

So I have no idea why it said Error when getting IngressClass nginx. Can anyone shed me some lights please?

Answer (score 2):

### Reproduction and what happens

I created a one node cluster using `kubeadm` on CentOS 7. And got the same error.

You and I were able to proceed further only because we missed this command at the beginning:

```
git checkout v1.12.1
```

The main difference is `ingress-class.yaml` has `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` in `v1.12.1` and `networking.k8s.io/v1` in `master` branch.

After I went here for the second time and switched the branch, I immediately saw this error:

```
$ kubectl apply -f common/ingress-class.yaml
error: unable to recognize "common/ingress-class.yaml": no matches for kind "IngressClass" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

That looks like other resources are not updated to be used on kubernetes `v1.22+` yet.

Please [see deprecated migration guide - v1.22 - ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122)

### How to proceed further

- I tested exactly the same approach on a cluster with `v1.21.4` and it worked like a charm. So you may consider downgrading the cluster.
- If you're not tight to using NGINX ingress controller (supported by `Nginx inc`, you can try `ingress nginx` which is developed by `kubernetes community`. I tested it on `v1.22`, it works fine. Please find
  [Installation on bare metal cluster](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal).

P.S. It may be confusing, but there are two free nginx ingress controllers which are developed by different teams. Also there's a third option - NGINX Plus which is paid and has more option. Please [see here the difference](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/intro/nginx-ingress-controllers/)

Comment: HI @moonkotte, thanks! That reminds me I did have an error when setting up the ingress-class at the beginning due to networking.k8s.io/v1beta1. So I changed manually the apiversion to networking.k8s.io/v1.

Let me try the Ingress Nginx you provieded. Thanks!